# Can't get launchOptions data from didFinishLaunchingWithOptions function

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications

My app needs to get some data from Remotenotification in order to push first page to the specific page like FACEBOOK app but now I can't get launchOptions data from didFinishLaunchingWithOptions function it always show:

> Cannot invoke 'objectForKey' with an argument list of type '(String)'.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    let userNotificationTypes = (UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound)

    // Register for Push Notitications, if running iOS 8
    if application.respondsToSelector("registerUserNotificationSettings:") {
        let settings:UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: userNotificationTypes, categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

    } else {
        // Register for Push Notifications before iOS 8
        application.registerForRemoteNotificationTypes( UIRemoteNotificationType.Badge | UIRemoteNotificationType.Sound | UIRemoteNotificationType.Alert )
    }

    if let launchOpts = launchOptions {
        var notificationPayload: NSDictionary = launchOptions.objectForKey(UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey) as NSDictionary
        //Cannot invoke 'objectForKey' with an argument list of type '(String)'.
    }

    return true
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below method :

```
if let notification = launchOpts[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] as? [NSObject : AnyObject] {

    // extra work           
}
```